Sitecore's media Filetype
I am trying to use IIS URL Rewrite to redirect access to the old domain to the URL of the new domain.
I want to block unwanted redirects. Would Sitecore Media be blocked by this condition ?
<condition
<add input=“{REQUEST_FILENAME}” matchType=“IsFile” negate=“true” />.
</>.

I would like to know if Sitecore media is considered a File.

I don't believe the media urls are considered as part of file request.  Although you can add below condition to exclude the media urls from the condition inside the redirect rule.
<rule name="" stopProcessing="true">
 <conditions>
  <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern=".*(-/media).*" negate="true" />
  <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern=".*(~/media).*" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
</rule>

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
